# Infecting yeast with viruses

Tags: virology, infection, yeast

Is there any virus, either natural or engineered, known to infect yeast through mechanisms similar to phages/human viruses, that is, by horizontal contamination mediated by extracellular viral particles?

I have found examples of eukaryotic viruses *replicating* in yeast (Zhao, *Microb Cell*, 2017 - [link](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5657823/)) but it seems that natural yeast viruses only transmit through mating or vertical transmission, without extracellular steps (Luque, *Viruses*, 2018 - [link](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6164181/)).

Has anybody ever reported, say, non-specific mechanisms like VSV-G mediated fusion, to fuse virions with yeasts?